# I am unable to get data through AJAX using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass value through ajax in .php file i.e. data:{num:val}. But value is not passing. I hav tried to display value through alert() but it is not showing anything.

```
  <form method="post" id="frm" name="new" onsubmit="return false;">
        Enter a Value: <input name="value1" type="text" id="num"><Br/><Br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Click" id="click">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(
                $('#click').on(
                function(){
                    var val=$('num').val();
                    alert(val);
                    jQuery.ajax({
                            method:'POST',
                            url:'table_php.php',
                            data:{num:val},
                            success: function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                            }
                });
                }
                )
                );
    </script>
```

Here is my table_php.php file

```
<?php
echo $var=$_POST["num"];
if(isset($var)&&!empty($var))
{
 echo "hello";
}
```

Comment: `$('num')` should be `$('#num')`.  You're selecting by `id`, not by element name.

Comment: My question is whether you are getting value in prompt `alert(val);`  ?

Comment: I have changed from $('num') to $('#num') but problem is still there.

Comment: I am trying to get data i.e. data:{num:val}, in another file

Comment: _"Deprecation Notice: The **jqXHR.success()**, jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks **are removed as of jQuery 3.0**. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two problems in your code.

-> Incorrect syntax `$("#click").on(function()` it is changed to `$("#click").click(function()`. If you are using on the syntax should be like this

```
$( "#click" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

->Then `var val=$('num').val();` num is an id so put `#` as `var val=$('#num').val();`

Now it is working fine means alert is now showing.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(
  $("#click").click(function(){
                    var val=$('#num').val();
                    alert(val);
                    jQuery.ajax({
                            method:'POST',
                            url:'table_php.php',
                            data:{num:val},
                            success: function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                            }
                });
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="frm" name="new" onsubmit="return false;">
        Enter a Value: <input name="value1" type="text" id="num"><Br/><Br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Click" id="click">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it working now on your php script? alert is showing on client side and data is passing.

Comment: yes, thanks.... but it is not getting response from another file

Comment: In which file ?

Comment: this file---- url:'table_php.php'

Comment: My answer is working for me on php side also I have tested it. In console i can see the result of echo. In php side you have to edit your condition as `if(!isset($var)&&!empty($var))` other wise both echo will print ie, content of `$var` and hello.

Comment: When I click on ok of alert result, in console my whole jquery code is appearing

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of an input by id in jQuery you must add a `#` before the name of the id. Replace this:

```
var val=$('num').val();
```

with this:

```
var val=$('#num').val();
```

Comment: Some explanation as to why/what you did would be helpful to the OP.

Comment: if you want to get the value of an input by id in jQuery you must add # before the name of the id. try it it will be work

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @Darsh: Define "not working".  We can't see your screen or debug on your computer for you.  How specifically does it fail?

Comment: delete onsubmit="return false;" and change $('#click').on("click",func....... +change the type of  <input type="submit"  to  <input type="button"